# Ghost 12 - can't multicast across subnets

Tags: multicast, ghost-blog, disk-imaging

Is there some trick so that I can multicast a Ghost image across subnets?  I've tried -TTL7 on the server and -JS=7 on the clients (# of hops).

Comment: What? Please explain...

Comment: @zixuan I'm trying to image machines with ghost, multicasting from one subnet or vlan to another.  I can't get the clients to see the server.